# Get static IPs from Global accelerator-cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, output, aws-cloudformation, static-ip-address, aws-global-accelerator

I'm trying to output static IPs from the AWS global accelerator, but according to [AWS docs](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-globalaccelerator-accelerator.html), the only available attributes are `AcceleratorArn` and `DnsName`. Is there some way I can output the static IPs?
See below sample CF script

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: CloudFormation template to deploy Global Accelerator
Parameters:
LoadbalancerARN:
        Description: Application Load Balancer ARN to be used as Global Accelerator endpoint
        Type: String
Resources:
    SampleAccelerator:
    Type: 'AWS::GlobalAccelerator::Accelerator'
    Properties:
        Name: MySampleAccelerator
        IpAddressType: "IPV4"
        Enabled: true
    SampleListener:
        Type: 'AWS::GlobalAccelerator::Listener'
        Properties:
            AcceleratorArn: !Ref SampleAccelerator
            Protocol: TCP
            PortRanges:
            - FromPort: '80'
                ToPort: '80'
    UsWest2EndpointGroup:
        Type: 'AWS::GlobalAccelerator::EndpointGroup'
        Properties:
            ListenerArn: !Ref SampleListener
            EndpointGroupRegion: us-west-2
            EndpointConfigurations:
            - EndpointId: !Ref LoadbalancerARN
                ClientIPPreservationEnabled: true
Outputs:
    AcceleratorDNS:
    Description: DNS for Global Accelerator
    Value: !GetAtt SampleAccelerator.DnsName
```

Comment: In general, if something is not available via the `CloudFormation`, the idea is to implement a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html). There is [DescribeAccelerator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/global-accelerator/latest/api/API_DescribeAccelerator.html) call you can use which provides IP Address details.